# Adding a raw select statement to the Knex query builder

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Using Knex to make queries to my Postgres DB. I have a function that provides a "base" query using the Knex QueryBuilder. This works fine until I need to add something raw to the SELECT statement. From what I can tell, running `.raw` always wants to return a result. I just need it to be added to the QueryBuilder, though, so it can be executed by a different part of my app.

```
const baseQuery = knex
    .select(newUserFields)
    .from('users')
    .leftJoin('user_roles', 'users.id', 'user_roles.user_id')
    .leftJoin('roles', 'user_roles.role_id', 'roles.id')
    .leftJoin('role_permissions', 'roles.id', 'role_permissions.role_id')
    .leftJoin(
        'permissions',
        'permissions.id',
        'role_permissions.permission_id'
    )
    .groupBy(
        'users.id',
        'users.email',
        'users.name',
        'users.status',
        'users.created_at',
        'users.password_reset_expiration',
        'users.password',
        'users.password_reset_token'
    )
    .orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc');
```

I need to add the following to the select:

```
knex.raw('to_json(array_agg(distinct roles.name)) as roleNames')
knex.raw('to_json(array_agg(distinct permissions.name)) as permissionNames')
```

How can I add these raw selects to the base query so that the base query can then be passed to a different function as a `QueryBuilder` and added to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cool thing about `knex` is that it is a **queryBuilder**, which allows you to call the methods without any limits about the **order of calls**. That means that you can just construct your base query in a function, and then attach to it additional things (such as additional columns).

In your case you just can call another time to select (knex will join the select calls)

```js
// base-query.js
export const getBaseQuery = () => knex
  .select(newUserFields)
  .from('users')
  .leftJoin('user_roles', 'users.id', 'user_roles.user_id')
  .leftJoin('roles', 'user_roles.role_id', 'roles.id')
  .leftJoin('role_permissions', 'roles.id', 'role_permissions.role_id')
  .leftJoin('permissions', 'permissions.id', 'role_permissions.permission_id')
  .groupBy(
    'users.id',
    'users.email',
    'users.name',
    'users.status',
    'users.created_at',
    'users.password_reset_expiration',
    'users.password',
    'users.password_reset_token'
  )
  .orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc');

// other-file.js
import {getBaseQuery} from 'base-query';

const enhancedQuery = getBaseQuery().select([
  knex.raw('to_json(array_agg(distinct roles.name)) as roleNames'),
  knex.raw('to_json(array_agg(distinct permissions.name)) as permissionNames'),
]);

const results = await enhancedQuery;
```

Another cool way that I'm using heavily, solves the following requirement: Sometimes I need to change an internal query from the outside, I use the [`modify`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify)
For example, I have a `getProducts` method which execute a `select` query and do some data transformation.
In order to implement `getProductById` which needs to return the **same data structure** (it is just need to filter the base query) I pass a queryModifier method which modifies the original query.

```js
async function getProducts(queryModifier) {
  const products = await knex
    .select('*')
    .from('products')
    .modify((queryBuilder) => {
      if (typeof queryModifier === 'function') {
        return queryModifier(queryBuilder);
      }
    });

  return products.map(someDataTransformation);
}

async function getProductById(id) {
  return getProducts((qb) => {
    return qb.where('id', id);
  });
}
```